# php download not working for &

Tags: php, download

I have this php function to download files from my public_html.

```
function download($file){
$dir = "RepList/";
$path = $dir.$file;

if(!file_exists($path))
{
    die("Error : The file does not exists !");
    }else{
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    header("Content-Typr: application/w3g");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    readfile($path);
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['download']))
{
    if(!empty($_GET['download']))
    {
        $file = $_GET['download'];
        download($file);
    }
}
```

For download I use something like:

```
<a class="download"  id="download'.$i.'_" href="../download.php?download='.$cc->EList[$i]->getEName().'" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

If I have "&" symbol in my file name, I will receive "Error : The file does not exists !".
I worked on this like 1 year ago and now I want to fix the error.

Any advice? Something easy & fast.

Comment: Content-Typr: is that just a typo here?

Comment: it`s extension if I am not wrong

Comment: @user2039923 user602088 wanted to say, Is there any spelling mistake in "Content-Typr" in your code here? It sould be "Content-Type"..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use `urlencode()` function and change creating HTML link to:

```
<a class="download"  id="download'.$i.'_" href="../download.php?download='.urlencode($cc->EList[$i]->getEName()).'" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

otherwise `&` character is treated as variables separator in url

Comment: @ShaunakShukla $_GET is automatically urldecoded, so you don't need it

Comment: where in dowload()? I changed in html, now I receive File not exists for all items.

Comment: @user2039923 you don't need to add urldecode anywhere

Comment: i added here ... urlencode($cc->EList[$i]->getEName()).'" target="_blank">Download</a>

Comment: @Marcin Nabialek Thanks, I know it, but it was out of my mind when I read urlencode() here, so added urldecode() in comment.. you are right!!

Comment: I encode the file name in html and then in download fuction I decode it like urldecode() for $file = urldecode($file);  right?

Comment: @user2039923 Where do you have anything about urldecode in my answer? If you read comments, read them carefully

Comment: For me this does not work... Isn`t there a way to make it work only changing in the function. before it runs this condition if(!file_exists($path)

Comment: @user2039923 Are you sure that path is correct? Try to add `echo realpath($path);` before if - it will display you the whole path and make sure this file exists

Comment: The solution is good but the encoder does not work properly. thanks